# Stack trace while debugging a rails application using Rubymine

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, stack-trace, rubymine

I use Rubymine as my IDE and use it for debugging any rails applications that I work on. Whenever a breakpoint is hit, I want to look at the stack trace and get an idea of the code flow. However, I notice that the stack trace is mostly full of Rails methods, like activesupport etc, and those from the application(my code) end up being lost. This is especially true when any filters are involved, or towards the beginning of a request(when it goes into controller).

Is it possible to exclude the rails code from filling up the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

RubyMine makes no distinction (does not sandbox) the framework code. That is why you can't step through the execution of a Rails program in RubyMine and exclude framework code.

Comment: Might be recent:  Settings → Build,... → Debugger → Stepping → 'Ignore non-project sources'.
Doesn't help with the stack trace issue though...